# Problems when recognizing wifi connection

Tags: wifi, networking

I recently installed elementary on my laptop, but the wifi is recognized with a low signal percentage although it is on the side of the modem and when I am a bit far away it does not even recognize it. The only solution is to use ethernet. any solution?
my computer is this.
I believe I am not the first to have this problem, but I can't seem to find similar question in Elementary forums.

[image]

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as **Answer** that helped solving your problem. If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type in the terminal:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

Let me know if that solves your problem